# Python scrapy does not go deeper

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm using Python2.7 and Scrapy 1.0.4. The following crawls are tested one by one in Shell and worked. However when I put them together, it seems Scrapy won't go deeper after the first level.

```
import scrapy

class trbSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "trb"
allowed_domains = ["dmoz.org"]
start_urls = [
    "http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/journal/01912615",
]

def parse(self, response):
    print '------ crawling root dir ------'
    for href in response.css('a.volLink::attr("href")'):
        url = response.urljoin(href.extract())
        print url
        yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse_volume)

def parse_volume(self, response):
    print '------ crawling sub dir ------'
    for href in response.css('div.currentVolumes a::attr("href")'):
        url = response.urljoin(href.extract())
        yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse_page)

def parse_page(self, response):
    print '------ crawing authors name'
    for authors in response.css('li.authors::text'):
        yield {'authors': authors.extract()}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's likely you have that behavior because this line:

```
allowed_domains = ["dmoz.org"]
```

You should either remove it or use:

```
allowed_domains = ["sciencedirect.com"]
```

Note that `allowed_domains` does not affect the `start_urls` but it filters out any other URL outputted by the spider callbacks.